# Strange behavior of switch condition

Tags: c

As i know below code should throw error and it's throwing error as it should.

**Error**

> test.c:6:1: warning: switch condition has boolean value [-Wswitch-bool]
>    switch(num1 > num2)
>
> **I am using gcc compiler.**

```
int num1, num2;
scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);
switch(num1 > num2)
{

   case 0:
    printf("%d is greatest\n",num2 );
    break;

    case 1:
    printf("%d is the greatest \n",num1 );
        break;

    default:
        printf("both are equall\n");
        break;


}
```

But if removing default case then it works without any error

```
int num1, num2;
scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);
switch(num1 > num2)
{

   case 0:
    printf("%d is greatest\n",num2 );
    break;

    case 1:
    printf("%d is the greatest \n",num1 );
        break;

}
```

it would be great if anyone can clear **why it's working if removing default case**.

**I think it's gcc compiler bug.**

Comment: `default` in this case is meaningless as the value of a boolean is either 0 or 1 and you covered both cases.

Comment: Please post the actual message.

Comment: Using switch with a boolean expression is a poor idea in the first place. Write your code straight forward with `if/else`: it will be more readable and you won't ned to cope with this kind of warnings. Rule of thumb: if you get any warning there is a gooid chance that you did something weird.

Comment: @machine_1 thanks for the response. i know that here default is useless, but my question is why there is no error if not using default.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviour make complete sense.

The expression num1 > num2 is a boolean, so possible values are 0 or 1, when you define both, you are defining all the possibilities, so the default statement doesn't make sense.
So taking a look at the code:

```
switch(num1 > num2) -> only 2 possible solutions: 0 or 1
    case 0: -> This is the false value
    ...
    case 1: -> This is the true value
    ...
    default: -> We run out of possible values, so default is undefined.
```

Is more clear if you do something like this:

```
int num1, num2;
scanf("%d%d", &num1, &num2);
if(num1 > num2)
{
    printf("%d is greatest\n",num2 );
} 
else 
{
    printf("%d is the greatest \n",num1 );
}
```

Anyway is still not valid, because you are not taking in consideration num1 == num2

Comment: That should produce a warning at most (well, unless one has warnings promoted to errors)

Comment: https://repl.it/@PauloDiogo1/IndolentStupidGravity it Warns... `warning: switch condition has boolean value [-Wswitch-bool]`

Comment: @Paulo And it does for both snippets.

Comment: The use of a switch statement with a boolean is not the best possible.

Comment: @ÓscarAndreu thanks for the response.
i know that using boolean in switch condition is not a good idea.
also aware that here default is useless, but my question is why there is no error if not using default.

Comment: @satya-prakash-patel you are really welcome, short answer could be that because a boolean have only 2 possible values, when you add the default you are adding a third one, and this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

the expression `num1 > num2` can only return two values `0` or `1`. To have some additional values you need to make it a bit more complicated

```
switch(num1 > num2 ? 1 : (num1 == num2 ? 2 : 0))
```

and the expression inside the switch will return `1` when `num1 > num2`, `2` if `num1 == num2` or `0` if `num1 < num2`

Another form:

```
switch((num1 > num2) * 1 + (num1 == num2) * 2)
```